# Setting label to visible in an action listener

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

I have a JFrame with a button on it. When the user presses the button, a time consuming series of actions are performed. I have a JLabel on the form that says "Please wait" that I want to become visible while the actions are being performed and then go invisible when they are completed. So, I put `label.setVisible(true)` at the beginning of the action listener and `label.setVisible(false)` at the end, but nothing happens.

It seems like the displaying of the label was being queued until the actions were finished, so it just goes visible and then immediately invisible. How can I make sure the label becomes visible before continuing with the rest of the code in the action listener?

Comment: As per Reimeus suggestion (+1) you could have a look at [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15803893/java-swing-processing-status/15804124#15804124) for some ideas

Answer (score 3):

Use a [SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html). When the button is clicked call [execute](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html#execute%28%29). Update the `JLabel` when [done](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html#done%28%29).